# Python - Getting fields from http header on server side

Tags: python, http-headers, webapp2

I need to know the date/time of client requests.

[I suppose] these informations are embeded in header part of post http requests.

So, how do I get them in a webapp2.RequestHandler class?

```
class GetPostHeaderFields(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        <date or time or datetime whatever> = ???
```

Tanks for any help.

Comment: No, that information is not embedded in a client's request headers. The HTTP standard doesn't provide for such information to be added.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the framework you are using. In case of webapp2 it is available as a dictionary object in `request.headers` . See [link](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#getting-the-current-request)

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')
        #Access request headers here
        request.headers['Cookie'] = 'test=value' #Could be anything like Authorization, etc
```

In case of Django you can access it as a dictionary object in `request.META`, See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)